# How Do I collapse rows on null values in t-sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, row

I'm in a weird situation with my query. My objective is to display the total deposits and withdrawals from multiple transactions for each person and display them. I am getting multiple rows that I need to collapse into one. This all needs to happen in one query

```
SELECT
       lastname,
       firsname,
       case when upper(category) = 'W' then sum(abs(principal)) end as Withdrawal,
       case when upper(category) = 'D' then sum(abs(principal)) end as Deposit,
       description
FROM
       table1 
       JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
       JOIN table3 ON table2.c = table3.c 
WHERE 
       description = 'string'
GROUP BY
       lastname,
       firstname,
       description,
       category
```

my result is

```
 lastname    firstname    Withdrawal    Deposit    description
 john         smith       null           140.34    string
 john         smith       346.00          null     string
 jane         doe         null           68.03     string
 jane         doe         504.00          null     string
```

and I am looking for

```
 lastname    firstname    Withdrawal    Deposit    description
 john         smith       346.00        140.34     string
 jane         doe         504.00        68.03      string
```

adding principal into the group does not work. any help on solving this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove category from group by and sum outside the case?

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation . . . the `case` is the argument to the `sum()`:

```
select lastname, firsname,
       sum(case when upper(category) = 'W' then abs(principal) end) as Withdrawal,
       sum(case when upper(category) = 'D' then abs(principal) end) as Deposit, 
       description
from table1 join
     table2
     on table2.id = table1.id join
     table3 
     on table3.c = table2.c
where description = 'string'
group by lastname, firstname, description
```

Comment: useful solution.

Comment: Yes this worked in combination with xQbert's suggestion! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Subquery

```
select t.lastname, t.firsname,sum(t.Withdrawal) Withdrawal ,sum(t.Deposit) Deposit,t.description from(
select lastname, firsname,
       isnull(case when upper(category) = 'W' then abs(principal) end,0) as Withdrawal,
       isnull(case when upper(category) = 'D' then abs(principal) end,0) as Deposit,
description
from table1 join
     table2
     on table2.id = table1.id join
     table3
     on table3.c = table2.c
where description = 'string'
)t group by t.lastname, t.firstname, t.description, t.category
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT lastname,firsname,
       SUM(case when upper(category) = 'W' then abs(principal) end) as Withdrawal,
       SUM(case when upper(category) = 'D' then abs(principal) end) as Deposit,
       description
FROM
       table1 
       JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
       JOIN table3 ON table2.c = table3.c 
WHERE 
       description = 'string'
GROUP BY
lastname,firstname,description
```